# C# RestSharp PUT method and send raw bytes (protobuf)

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, restsharp

How to send a byte array using HTTP PUT method? 
Method `AddFile` of the class `RestRequest` sends extra headers. 
Method `AddParameter` takes an `Object` type.

How I do it:

```
byte[] data;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(ms, query);
    data = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close();
}
var client = new RestClient(ServerPath);
var request = new RestRequest(RequestPath, Method.PUT);
request.AddFile("stream", x => new MemoryStream(data), string.Empty);
client.ExecuteAsync(request, responce => Debug.WriteLine(responce.Content));
```

But on server side I see extra headers

> -------------------------------28947758029299
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="stream"; filename=""
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   [RAW DATA HERE]
>   -------------------------------28947758029299--

Extra headers make query unreadable. What I do wrong?

Comment: What is the server *expecting* this to look like? should the payload just be the raw body? the use of `AddFile` *suggests* it is actually expecting multi-part , but that doesn't match the listed content-type/-disposition. For example, is this as simple as `WebClient` with `client.UploadData(address, "PUT", data);` ?

Comment: Server expecter only raw data, without headers. If I use request.AddObject(data) server see it as Length=29&Rank=1&SyncRoot=System.Byte%5B%5D&IsReadOnly=False&IsFixedSize=True&IsSynchronized=False

Comment: if you don't have headers, then it doesn't sound like HTTP... HTTP *has headers*. The presence of headers should not unduly impact it.

Comment: OK, there is me second client for service, first I write for android, now I write for WP8, on android HttpClient I see not this problem, but on RestSharp it is

Comment: then you need to inspect the http to see what exactly is different. You could also just use HttpClient on WP8 (http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http ?)

Comment: WP8 has not HttpClient just WebClient. But WebClient cant put binary data. This is the reason why I use restSharp

Comment: that might be more convincing if I hadn't just linked to the MS-provided HttpClient download on NuGet...

Comment: "This package provides a programming interface for modern HTTP applications on .NET Framework 4, Silverlight 4 and 5, Windows Phone 7.5 and 8. This package includes HttpClient for sending requests over HTTP, as well as HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage for processing HTTP messages.

This package also supports Portable Class Libraries."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Marc Gravell.
Solution:

> ```
>         var client = new HttpClient();
>         var httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
>         client.PutAsync(Path, httpContent);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I struggle on this for sometimes and finally found the solution
the magic is to give as request body without parameter name

```
// file to send
IFormFile file
byte[] buffer;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    buffer = ms.ToArray();
}
var uploadDoc = new RestRequest("ressource", Method.POST);
uploadDoc.RequestFormat = DataFormat.None;
uploadDoc.AddParameter("", buffer, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = new RestClient("baseUrl").Execute(uploadDoc);
```

hope it can help others